# how can add a filter to my CGridView when i send a result of some findAll

Tags: yii, filter, cgridview

I send a result  of  combine some findAll()   to a CGridView , how can add a filter to my CGridView

**controller**:

```
$model1=mymodel::model->finAll($criteria1);
$model2=mymodel::model->finAll($criteria2);
$model3=mymodel::model->finAll($criteria3);
///**   
$data=some foreach and combine molde1,model2,model3


**///
$provider = new CArrayDataProvider( $data );
        $this->render('list2', array(
            'model' => $provider
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement method in your model (may be based on `model::search()` method) which returns you search criteria:

```
public function getSearchCriteria()
{
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('attribute_1',$this->attribute_1,true);
    $criteria->compare('attribute_2',$this->attribute_2);
    // Other attributes here

    return $criteria
}
```

Further you should merge your `$criteria1`, `$criteria2`, `$criteria3` with this criteria:

```
$myModel = new MyModel('search');
$myModel ->unsetAttributes();
if(isset($_GET['MyModel']))
   $myModel->attributes=$_GET['MyModel'];

$criteria1->mergeWith($myModel->getSearchCriteria(), 'AND');
$criteria2->mergeWith($myModel->getSearchCriteria(), 'AND');
$criteria3->mergeWith($myModel->getSearchCriteria(), 'AND');

$model1=mymodel::model->finAll($criteria1);
$model2=mymodel::model->finAll($criteria2);
$model3=mymodel::model->finAll($criteria3);
///**   
$data=some foreach and combine molde1,model2,model3
**///

$provider = new CArrayDataProvider( $data );

$this->render('list2', array(
   'model' => $provider
));
```

And in view:

```
function getFilterParam($modelName, $attributeName, $default = ''){
    $value = Yii::app()->request->getParam($modelName);
    if(is_array($value) && isset($value[$attributeName])){
        return $value[$attributeName];
    }
    else{
        return $default;
    }
}

$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'сolumns'=>array(
        'attribute_1' => array(
            'header' => 'Attribute_1',
            'filter' => CHtml::textField('MyModel["attribute_1"]', getFilterParam('MyModel', 'attribute_1')),
            'name' => 'attribute_1',
        ),
        'attribute_2' => array(
            'header' => 'Attribute_2',
            'filter' => CHtml::textField('MyModel["attribute_2"]', getFilterParam('MyModel', 'attribute_2')),
            'name' => 'attribute_2',
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: getSearchCriteria() is search method or is different?

Comment: had i get dataprovider from $mymodel?  similati:$dataProvider = new CArrayDataProvider($mymodel);

Comment: @maryam CArrayDataProvider takes only arrays. After merging criteras you are doing everything as well as in the your example (combine molde1,model2,model3 and create new CArrayDataProvider).

Comment: in line $myModel = new MyModel('search'); what is 'search'? 'search is true or 'getSearchCriteria',

Comment: @maryam This is a string which sets scenario of model. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#scenario-detail

Comment: I'm confused can i send for you my code? my email is: masoudy.maryam@gmail.com please send a eamil